# Ajax.BeginForm is not calling the action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I have the following code inside ym asp.net mvc razor view:_

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ManageCustomAsset", "Customer", new AjaxOptions

    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
        UpdateTargetId = "customassettableBody",
        LoadingElementId = "progress",
        HttpMethod= "POST",
        OnSuccess="submitform"
    }))
    {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         <div>
     <span class="f"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.CustomAsset.CustomerName) </span>       
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomAsset.CustomerName, new { disabled = "disabled" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomAsset.CustomerName)                                              

     @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.CustomAsset.CustomerName)

    </div>


    <div>
        <span class="f"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.CustomAsset.CustomAssetType.Name) </span> 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.CustomAsset.CustomTypeID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.CustomAssetType>)ViewBag.CustomTypes).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
            Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name), 
            Value = option.ID.ToString(),
            Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.CustomAsset != null) && (option.ID == Model.CustomAsset.CustomTypeID)
        }), "Choose...") <i class=" icon icon-blue icon-star-on "></i>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.CustomAsset.CustomTypeID)
    </div>
           <div>
     <span class="f"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.CustomAsset.Description) </span>       
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomAsset.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomAsset.Description)                                              



    </div>                                      






           <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>

}
```

but when I click on the form it will not reach the following action method , what si happening si that the loading image will be shown and then nothing will happen, and I will not even get an error ???:-

```
[HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       [CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "CustomAsset")]
       public ActionResult ManageCustomAsset(CustomerCustomAssetJoin ccaj)
       {

           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               try
               {
                   string ADusername = User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
                   repository.InsertOrUpdateCustomerCustomAsset(ccaj.CustomAsset, ADusername);
                   //  repository.Save();

                   return PartialView("_customerCustomAsset", ccaj);

               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {

                   //ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error occurred: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                   return Json(new { IsSuccess = "False", description = ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
               }

           }

           return View(ccaj);


       }
```

Answer (score 1):

are you add this js?

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Example:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("Thanks", "text/html");
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="result"></div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: yes I already added @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

Comment: have you seen in browser this bundle loads all js ?

Comment: yes if I change the action method name, then it will call it successfully ,, but for the ManageCustomAsset action method it is not working . so yes the scripts are loading correctly...

Answer (score 0):

This may be something to do with the anti-forgery token. Your implementing the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on your action but you have `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`commented out in your view.

Comment: I uncommented it , but still the same. I actually comment it as I thought it might cause the problem .. but unfortunately still I am getting the same behaviour... if the problem is realted to this atleast the call will reach the action method and then an error will occur,, but in my case the ajax.begin form will not reach the action method. I have inserted a breakpoint , but it did not reach it ..